# iOS Volume Control via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

I'm fairly new to iOS dev, and I am currently developing an app that is to be controlled by a Bluetooth peripheral. If a peripheral sends a signal, the phone needs to increment its system volume. I am only finding examples with sliders. Is there any way to increase system volume? Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: No, You can't control the iOS system volume. you can only control music volume using sliders.

Comment: so, there is no way of controlling media || system volume just by pressing a button of the peripheral and sending it through bluetooth?

Comment: You can control media volume, on event from peripheral event. please take a look at below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to modify the system volume. This has been intentionally removed (there used to be supported ways).

There is a deprecated way (since iOS 7) that currently works, but may go away in any future release. You can use `[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] setVolume:]` to set the master volume.

The new supported way to change the system volume is to open an `MPVolumeView` and let the user modify the volume. But there's no programmatic interface. You *can* hunt around in the view for the sliders and adjust them through, though. This is really fragile; sometimes the structure changes between OS versions, and Apple may move this view into another process in the future (as they've done with several other views that they don't want you messing with). I do not recommend this approach and am not going to write up code to do it (since the deprecated `setVolume:` still works). But it is possible.

Again, this is all unsupported stuff, and Apple may reject your app over it.

Comment: thanks for a detailed response! have a lovely day :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentVolume: Float = 0.0
let mpVolumeView = MPVolumeView()
func volumeSliderControl(_ volume: Float) {
    let volumeSlider = (mpVolumeView.subviews.filter { NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider" }.first as! UISlider)
    currentVolume = currentVolume + volume
    currentVolume = currentVolume > 1.0 ? 1.0 : currentVolume < 0.0 ? 0.0 : currentVolume
    debugLog("currentVolume: \(currentVolume)")
    volumeSlider.setValue(currentVolume, animated: false)
    volumeSlider.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
}
```

For above function, just pass volume range from 0 to 1 in Float
This code to control music/media volume only.

Comment: thank you! I will implement it and report the results